# Can I use FTP to get around the connection limits of IIS?

Tags: windows-xp, ftp, iis

I know that Windows XP limits IIS to 10 connections. I have a web service that copies files from the server to 20 terminals. 10 terminals work fine, but terminal number 11 gets no connection.

If I were to copy the files from the server to the terminals with **FTP** (still on the IIS), would this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a license limitation and Windows XP has a 10 inbound connection limit. If you go above this, you are technically breaking the license.

As far as I remember, FTP is connection limited and will not allow going about 10 connections.

Comment: thanks for the help !, is there any way to copy file from the server (windows-XP) to 20 or more terminals without use IIS  ?

Comment: Well, technically, you will be breaking the Windows License, but, you can use Filezilla FTP Server - http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server or Apache Web Server - http://httpd.apache.org/